# React Native on port 80

Tags: react-native

We are working in an open space and the ports are closed in the router. Is there a way to configure React Native to port 80 (which is whitelisted)?

```
 > react-native run-android
```

I thought this would be easier than contacting the IT people and opening the right ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
react-native start --port 80
```

After that open up Dev Settings in app and set Debug server host & port